# Comparing dates in Excel

Tags: excel, date

I'm trying to compare date in excel to return a value.

I want to see...

```
if date of birth + today() is less than DATE(2021,9,1) years then output 6
if date of birth + today() is less than DATE(2021,9,1) years then output 5
if date of birth + today() is less than DATE(2021,9,1) years then output 4
if date of birth + today() is less than DATE(2021,9,1) years then output 3
```

This is for a school project. I'm struggling to understand the date concept.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanx for reading,

Sam

Comment: There is no difference in the four criteria.  They all say `if date of birth + today() is less than DATE(2021,9,1)` with different outputs.  Are you wanting how many years old the subject was on the 1st of September of 2021?

Comment: As pointed out by scott craner, do re-write the expressions with different criteria.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, imagining that cell `A1` contains the date of birth:

```
=IF((A1 + today()) < DATE(2021,9,1), 6)
=IF((A1 + today()) < DATE(2021,9,1), 5)
=IF((A1 + today()) < DATE(2021,9,1), 4)
=IF((A1 + today()) < DATE(2021,9,1), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

After going home and sleeping on it, I think I figured it out. I wanted my date to be static and check against pupil date of births to determine their age for a particular year. I already have a version of this which is dynamic and updates itself when the sheet is loaded. Here is what I did, where E3 is equal to a pupils date of birth...

```
=IF(E3="","",
IF(DATEDIF(E3,DATE(2021,9,1),"Y")+1>=11,6,
IF(DATEDIF(E3,DATE(2021,9,1),"Y")+1>=10,5,
IF(DATEDIF(E3,DATE(2021,9,1),"Y")+1>=9,4,
IF(DATEDIF(E3,DATE(2021,9,1),"Y")+1>=8,3,
"")))))
```

If there is an easier way to accomplish this I would relish feedback.

Thanx again to those of you who replied,

Sam

This is my dynamic version

```
=IF(E3="","",MAX(0,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR(E3+122),9,1),NOW(),"Y" )-4))
```

This calculates age

```
=IF(E3="","",
DATEDIF(E3,TODAY(),"Y") & "." &
DATEDIF(E3,TODAY(),"YM") & "." &
DATEDIF(E3,TODAY(),"MD")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, a date is stored as a number of days since 1/1/1900 (or 1904, not very important), you can subtract date2-date1 and that will return the number of days between the 2 dates.
With that logic, a simple formula to get your age from your birth date stored in E3 would be:

```
=INT((TODAY()-E3)/365)
```

Just for fun, enter a date in a cell, then Clear Formats. You will see the number of days.